# web development e-mail protection

Tags: security

Currenty, web sites gives generic messages to the users on invalid login attemps such as:

```
The username or password you entered is not valid
```

to protect e-mails from spammers. However, I read somewhere that this is not enough because sign up forms will warn user if the e-mail address is already taken. Therefore spammers can find valid e-mails by trying to fill registration forms not login forms.

The question: how can we prevent this? Is there a good way of handling this situation?

Comment: Just a comment, I think those ambiguous warnings might add security, but come at a considerable cost to the user who can't remember if he already registered.

Answer (score 1):

One quite nice way to prevent brute forcing is to add an increasing delay before checking.

A fairly good way is to add a 1 second delay before showing the error implying that the email is taken, then double that to 2 seconds, then 4 then 8 etc for the user. You could max this out at 16 seconds, or block the IP for 10 minutes after this for instance.

This way, real users get a 1, 2 or 4 second delay (not much), but bruteforcing becomes too laborious.

Comment: So what about real people with bad intentions? The "The username or password you entered is not valid" also eliminates the people, however with this approach we can only make things hard for bruteforcing.

Comment: Yes, but this still is nice for real users.